# How to make ngMessage for required fields only show when dirty or submitting a form?

Tags: angularjs, forms

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.0 RC0 and angular-messages. ng-messages dutifully shows error messages for those "required" fields when a form is initially loaded and pristine. So the newly loaded form page is filled up with error messages. This is not what I want. How to make ngMessage for required fields only show when those fields are dirty or submitting a form?

I have read the official doc, no clue. And tried to put "ng-show = "fieldName.$dirty"" in the ng-messages div, did not work. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use the `ng-if` attribute to check for `$dirty` on the tag that has `ng-messages`.

Example :

```html
<div ng-messages='myForm.myControl.$error' ng-if='myForm.myControl.$dirty'>
    <div ng-message='required'>Required field</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, for me this works only for required, but e.g. for input[type=email] the validation switches to invalid as soon the user starts typing

Comment: @maxb have you tried using `ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"`?. See [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), "Non-immediate (debounced) model updates" section.

Comment: If the user enters the field but doesn't provide input, $dirty isn't triggered. However, $touched will be. This is useful for required fields.

Comment: `ng-if` and `ng-messages` together cause some strange behavior in Angular Material.  If you ever see duplicate messages, switch to `ng-show`.

Answer (score 21):

The best way to do this is with $touched:

```
<div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.name.$error" ng-show="userForm.name.$touched">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Only if dirty:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.myField.$dirty && myForm.myField.$error">
    <div ng-message='required'>Required field</div>
</div>
```

Only if form is submitted:

```
<div ng-messages="myForm.$submitted && myForm.myField.$error">
    <div ng-message='required'>Required field</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is, if we validate when the form is submitted, then it will submit with the error data and we don't want that. But if we submit only if the form is valid, then the submit won't occur in case of an error and then the validation message won't show, but that is when we need it. Kind of funny :)

Comment: You don't want to submit an invalid form. Your ng-submit should check if form is $valid before calling the appropriate function on your scope/controller.

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using the ng-if suggested you could do something like...

```
<div ng-messages='myForm.myControl.$error' ng-if='submitted'>
   <div ng-message='required'>Required field</div>
</div>
```

And on your submit button add:

```
ng-click="submitted=true"
```

You'd probably want to change '$scope.submitted' back to false when you type again, so you could add this to your text/email input:

```
ng-keyup="submitted=false"
```

That way only the submit button will change '$scope.submitted' to true and everything else you do will set it to false, therefore hiding your error message until you click the submit button.

Comment: only issue is if you're displaying multiple errors they all get hidden onkeyup, but great solution I'm just trying to figure out how to make it work with multiple errors displayed

Comment: I actually need to work on a new project showing multiple errors so I'll get back on this once I've figured something clean out. If you haven't already? @mtpultz

Comment: If setting submitted=true on ng-click then how to call controller method at ng-click eg: ng-click="$ctrl.login()"?

Comment: @MicrosoftDeveloper ng-click="$crl.login(); submitted=true"

This should work, if not try a comma between them. I can't remember exactly which one is correct.

Comment: @MicrosoftDeveloper You could also just make a submitted variable in your controller and add `submitted=true` in your `$ctrl.login()` function.

Answer (score 5):

I did not want to show my message until there is any error or user tried to submit the page, and none of the above solution worked.

Finally I ended up successfully with this:

```
<form name='frmUser'>
..........
..........
<div ng-messages="frmUser.firstName.$error" 
     ng-show='frmUser.$submitted || frmUser.firstName.$dirty' role="alert">
      <div ng-message="required" class="err">Required</div>
      <div ng-message="maxlength" class="err">Maximum 50 characters.</div>
</div>
<input ng-model="model.first"
       name="firstName"
       type="text"
       ng-required="true"
       ng-maxlength="50"
       placeholder="Enter your first name" />

</form>
```

If you type anything which is not valid, then show the error

If you try to submit the page and you have not provided the required field it will show error.

Answer (score 3):

Do the error messages still appear after you have satisfied their conditions? In that case, have you remembered to take a dependency on `ngMessages` in your angular module? E.g.:

```
angular.module("exampleModule", ["ngMessages"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The error message disappear when I type something correct in the input box. That's like expected, no problem. The problem is: Those "required" fields are correctly empty when the page is just loaded. At this point of time, I do not want to see the error message. The error message "This field is required, please enter value!!!" should only appear when the user tries to submit, not when loading the page.....

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer helpful, but it didn't solve the problem of the error message hanging around forever.  I came up with a slightly more complex use of show and hide as follows:

```
<div class="help-block"
    ng-messages="addPlanForm.planName.$error"
    ng-show="addPlanForm.$submitted || addPlanForm.planName.$dirty || (addPlanForm.planName.$invalid && addPlanForm.planName.$touched)">
    <p ng-message="required" ng-hide="addPlanForm.planName.$valid">Your name is required.</p>
</div>
```

By adding ng-hide on the message generated when an error occurs, the message disappears when the user corrects the error.  Way cool.  I LOVE angular.

Answer (score 2):

Just Try this

```
<div ng-messages='myForm.fieldName.$error && (myForm.fieldName.$dirty || myForm.$submitted)' >
    <div ng-message='required'>Required field</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this and what was happening was my ng-messages were not appearing because the default browser behavior was not allowing invalid form submission with ng-required="true". To solve this you can decorate the form with novalidate. Here is the full working example for me:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="myForm.$valid && controllSideSubmitHandle()">
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="myScope.name" ng-required="true">
  <div ng-messages="myForm.$error || myForm.$submitted" style="color:maroon" role="alert" ng-if="myForm.name.$dirty || myForm.$submitted">
    <div ng-message="required">Name is required.</div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem with a css rule

```
[ng-messages] { display: none; color:red; } 
.ng-dirty [ng-messages] { display:block }
```

That's it..

Works like a charm for me.

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7qnWfByEjAqrY7bXigC2?p=preview)

Angular's use of classes is amazing, you can do so many things with it!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input required type="text" ng-model="model" name="field" ng-maxlength="13" ng-minlength="10">     
<div ng-messages="form.field.$error" ng-if='form.$submitted'>
            <p ng-message="required">Required</p>
            <p ng-message="maxlength">not a valid field. Length exceeds.</p>
            <p ng-message="minlength">not a valid field. Length is shorter.</p>
</div>
```

button type should be `submit` and this will work.

Comment: I have edited the answer. 
Hopefully it will help you with validations in angularJs

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AngularJS Material, a lot of this functionality comes out of the box! Just remember to put everything inside an `<md-input-container>`.

Here's a [codepen example](https://codepen.io/hubatish/pen/gxpgaZ) so you can see how it looks. This not only hides the error before the input has been clicked, it'll add some nice red styling and an animation for when it does show up!

Here's the actual code:

```
  <form name="books" novalidate>
    <md-input-container>
      <input ng-model="title" name="title" required/>
      <div ng-messages="books.title.$error">
        <div ng-message="required">Title is required</div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
  </form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to display this message outside md-input-cointainer?