# hide default error message in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, hide

How to hide a default error message in AngularJs? I tried **display:none;** . But, it won't work. I'm new to AngularJS. I want to hide the default error message and I want to show the error message when user onfocus the input textbox.

```
<p>
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" ng-model="firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/" required/>
    <span class="error" ng-messages="contact_form.first_name.$error">
        <span ng-message="required">First name should not be empty</span>
        <span ng-message="pattern" ng-show="contact_form.first_name.$error.pattern">Only alphabets allowed</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634394/how-to-make-ngmessage-for-required-fields-only-show-when-dirty-or-submitting-a-f/45333650#45333650

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need, `contact_form.first_name.$dirty` is used to check if field was changed or not

```
<form name="contact_form" novalidate>    
  <p>
      <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" ng-model="firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/" required/>
      <span class="error" ng-messages="contact_form.first_name.$error">
          <span ng-message="required" ng-show="contact_form.first_name.$error.required && contact_form.first_name.$dirty">First name should not be empty</span>
          <span ng-message="pattern" ng-show="contact_form.first_name.$error.pattern">Only alphabets allowed</span>
      </span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the use of contact_form.first_name.$dirty?

Comment: It is used to check case if input was interacted or not https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can create a variable to determine if the form have been sumbitted:

```
app.controller('NameController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.submitted = false;

    $scope.formProcess = function(form) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
        // logic
    }
}]);
```

Than in your view:

```
<form ng-submit="formProcess(form)">
    <p>
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" ng-model="firstName" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/" required/>
        <span class="error" ng-if="submitted" && ng-messages="contact_form.first_name.$error">
            <span ng-message="required">First name should not be empty</span>
            <span ng-message="pattern" ng-show="contact_form.first_name.$error.pattern">Only alphabets allowed</span>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Send</button>
    </p>
</form>
```